# Grammar of "so goes" in "And so goes an unusually heated example"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Would you explain the grammar of "so goes an unusually heated..." in the sentence below?

> "Impossible!" the first one shouts. Voices rise. **And so goes
>   an** unusually heated example of what some people call the mommy
>   wars.

*This is America,* "[Issues of Economics, Fairness Shape Debate on Working Mothers](http://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/a-23-2006-05-21-voa2-83127842/125427.html)"

Comment: What do you mean by the "grammar point" of the passage? What would you like to know about it?

Comment: "And so goes" is an idiom of sorts meaning roughly "this is typical".

Comment: The verb (*goes*) and subject (*example*) have been transposed from the usual order. As HL points out *so goes* is idiomatic for "proceeds in the usual way".

Answer (score 2):

It's used in the following sense:

> **So** *adverb*
>   In the way described or demonstrated; thus: *so it was that he was still a bachelor*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/so)

The sentence is *describing* the shout and raised voices as "an unusually heated example of what some people call the mommy wars".